# Spring + Scala + anonymous block or class

Tags: java, spring, scala

I don't know why but the class below doesn't work if instance variable text is private, but if I leave out private, it works.

Debugging the test in section "setField" I could see that the instance variable name should be "text" but it becomes "com$test$SimpleTest$$text"

```
package com.test
import org.testng.annotations.Test
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils

class SimpleTest {
  private var text = ""

  @Test
  def testValueOfX(): Unit = {
    val simpleTest = new SimpleTest
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(simpleTest,"text", "abc")

    println(
      Option[String](null)
        .map(v => v + " 123")
        .getOrElse {
          simpleTest.text + " 321"
    })
  }
}
```

I believe that the problem someway be the "getOrElse" because if I leave out too, it works.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Which line throws what error? How does removing `getOrElse` make it work?

Comment: This classe doesn't work if you try run it. The line throws `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(simpleTest,"text", "abc")` . If I put out instance variable `simpleTest.text` of the anonymous block, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala compiler has a right to compile your private field into an any working java code, as it doesn't affect interoperability (if you don't do any tricks). Spring's `setField` actually do such trick, as it makes your private field accessible (`setAccessible(true)` inside). Public fields are always compiling as is to give you appropriate interface from Java.

Use http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html to work with Scala reflection. Also [this article](http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/lang/en/1864/scala-reflection-accessing-an-objects-private-field-explained/) may be helpful.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562445/why-cant-i-have-a-private-var-val-with-the-same-name-as-a-getter-setter-or) is explanation why scalac uses another name for private field.

P.S. The reason why removing `.getOrElse(text)` make it work is because you don't use `text` anywhere but inside this piece of code.

Comment: About  `.getOrElse` actually if I put it out anonymous block, it works. The problem is when a instance variable is inside anonymous block. But I'm reading the articles.

Comment: anyway - compiler can do whatever it wants with your private field and this behaviour may change between versions of Scala, so you can't use java reflection - only scala reflectionn.

Comment: about experiment itself - I suspect it's not about block - `println(simpleTest.text)` also shouldn't work - or any actual usage. Because if you're just have putten `simpleTest.text` somewhere between lines - compiler knows that value is unused (actually it prints warning about that). Anyway, it's `scalac`'s internals and it's not a bug, so we can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

This class is only to show the problem, actually it is very different of real class. So I changed the strategy to receive an instance by @Autowired a method instead @Autowired a field.

```
package com.test
import org.testng.annotations.Test
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils

class SimpleTest {
  // item 1
  private var text = ""

  @Test
  def testValueOfX(): Unit = {
    val simpleTest = new SimpleTest
    ReflectionTestUtils.invokeSetterMethod(simpleTest, "text", "abc")

    println(
          Option[String](null)
        .map(v => v + " 123")
        .getOrElse {
        simpleTest.text + " 321"
      })
  }
  // item 2
  def setText(text: String): Unit = {
    this.text = text
  }
}
```

I'm not using @Autowired in this sample but in the real class I am. So if you need to get an instance follow instructions below.

Item 1 -> if I put on @Autowired it doesn't work because like said **dk14** Scala compiler has a right to compile your private field into an any working java code. So, the compiler change the field's name when it compiles the class

Item 2 -> I put on @Autowired in the setter method, it works.