# Scala: create public non-final class field from bytecode perspective

Tags: java, scala, javabeans, bytecode

In Scala, how to create a class field compiled to public non-final field (from bytecode perspective).

Similar to this (in Java):

```
public class Meh {
  public String field;
}
```

Comment: That's not possible in Scala AFAIK. Once you declare a `var` without restricting it to being private or private package, you get getters and setters, not a direct field access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's impossible in 'clean correct way'.
2. If you really want:

   - define variable as private[this]
   - call via java reflection setAccessible(true) for this field in constructor of companion object.
3. I don't know details behind your question, but I guess then in most cases adding some java to project will work better ;)

Comment: If the mangled field name doesn't matter, inline accessor forces it: `class C { private[this] var s: String = _ ; @inline private final def s(): String = this.s }` http://stackoverflow.com/q/12486992/1296806